# Finding the global maximum and minimum of a multivariable function

Tags: calculus

$f(x, y) = 4-y $ in the constraint $ (x, y, z) \in R^3 : x^2 + y^2=8, x+y+z=1 $

I don't know where to start. I tried finding critical points, and there are none. Am I supposed to study the points where the circumference and the plane intersect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using Lagrange Multipliers here, as there are constraints.

I think we can do it by inspection though. We know that $x^2 + y^2 = 8$. The third dimension $z = 1-x-y$ seems largely irrelevant, and is less a constraint than the definition of $z$.

To maximise $f(x,y)=4-y$, surely we should take the lower point of the circle $x^2+y^2=8$ where $x=0, y=-\sqrt{8}$.

To minimise $f(x,y)=4-y$, i.e. give the largest $y$ for a point in our set, take $x=0$, $y= \sqrt{8}$

Comment: If I wanted to use Lagrange, should I compute $\mathcal{L} (x, y, \lambda) = f(x, y) - \lambda g(x, y) - \lambda h(x, y) $?  With $g(x, y), h(x, y)$ being the constraints

Comment: Use two different parameters for the two constraints but otherwise yeah

Comment: Thank you very much!